# Stripping markers (provided in array) from text does not pass tests in Codewars

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

I'm trying to solve the [Strip Comments](https://www.codewars.com/kata/strip-comments/train/javascript) challenge on Codewars. The description of the problem is -

> Complete the solution so that it strips all text that follows any of a set of comment markers passed in. Any whitespace at the end of the line should also be stripped out.

Screenshot of the input and expected output -

[image]

The way I approached the problem was-

1. Split the input string into an array. Create a new array to hold the result.
2. For each character in the first array (input), if the character is not a marker, push it in the result array.
3. If the character is a marker, ignore all subsequent characters until a newline `\n` is encountered. At this point, resume pushing onto the result array.
4. Repeat till end of input array.
5. Join the result array, trim the string and return it.

My code -

```js
function solution(input, markers) {
  let markerFound = false;
  let stripped = [];
  let letters = input.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (markers.includes(letters[i])) {
      markerFound = true;
    }

    if (markerFound && letters[i] === "\n") {
      markerFound = false;
    }

    if (!markerFound) {
      stripped.push(letters[i]);
    }

  }
  return stripped.join("").trim();
}

console.log(solution("apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples", ["#", "!"]));
```

I'm not sure why the tests fail. The expected and returned outputs look the same to me -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple: there's a space after pears.

> Any whitespace at the end of the line should also be stripped out.

I guess you'll need another trim when pushing to the stripped array

```
stripped.push(letters[i].trim());
```

Comment: That takes off the space between the words as well, `Returned 'apples,pearsgrapesbananas'`.

But thanks for the idea, I think I know what has to be done.

Comment: Here's what worked - `return stripped.join('').replace(/\s\n/,'\n').trim();`

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(input, markers) {
  let isFounded = false;
  let letters = input.split('');
  let stripped = letters.reduce((acc , letter) => {
    if(markers.includes(letter)) isFounded = true;
    if(isFounded && letter === '\n') isFounded = false;
    if(!isFounded) acc.push(letter)
      return acc;
  }, [])
  
  return stripped.join('').replace(/\s\n/ , '\n').trim();
};
```